# Home Network is Inefficient and Slow

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have troubleshooted my network and I can't ever seem to get decent speeds. My router is a WNDR3400v2 (stock firmware, 802.11n, dual band) and I should be getting around 90 Mbps.

Whenever I had the family computer (on the first floor) plugged in (through Ethernet) to the router, it got about 90 Mbps. My computer (on the second floor) got only about 15 Mbps while the router was on the first floor. My computer uses a Belkin N600 DB wireless adapter. My Samsung Smart TV would also buffer when it was only a room away. My phone (GS3) never got above 30 Mbps and I couldn't get connection on one side of my room.

I recently moved the router upstairs and put a Belkin N600 DB wireless adapter in the family computer. Now the family computer gets only about 30 Mbps (max) even though it is directly under the router (separated by a floor). My computer gets about 20 Mbps and the TV buffers a lot.

I've tried changing the channel but it makes little to no difference. I used inSSIDer to find the best channel. I can never seem to connect to the router with the 5 GHz band. I have tried replacing the router but it never improved much. The mode for my router is "Up to 145 Mbps" and I have tried using "Up to 300 Mbps" but it didn't do anything. My password for my router is WPA2-PSK[AES] if that matters.

I do a bit of streaming (about 30 GB/month) and watch videos frequently. I understand that I won't be able to reach the same speeds as I would if it were through Ethernet, but 30% efficiency is very low. 
I experience buffering when streaming, and all streaming is done through LAN.  I stream from the family computer to my computer, the TV, and my iPad.

I can't run Ethernet cables through the wall (sadly), and I'd prefer to not buy another router as it would be the fourth in the time frame of about a year.

If anyone could help, it would be very appreciated. I need to fix these slow speeds.

Edit: Both of the wireless adapters are using 20 and 40 MHz frequencies.

Comment: What 802.11 mode are you connected at on these devices ( update your question ) also what frequency are you connected at on these devices ( update your question ).

Comment: @Ramhound: I checked the advanced adapter properties and it says the frequency of both are 20/40 MHz. It doesn't say a mode though. The only options are Bandwidth_2.4G, Bandwidth_5G, Network Type (infrastructure), and WiFi Config (performance).

Comment: 20/40 MHz would be the channel looking for either 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz I assume you don't have one of the new tri-channel 802.11 AC routers...

Comment: @Ramhound: Sadly, I do not. How would I go about finding the mode since it isn't in the advanced settings?

Comment: Yes; it is in the options you listed the two choices you just failed to indicate which one was selected you have a single band router capable of both 2.4 and 5 GhZ

Comment: @Ramhound: My apologies. My router is dual band but I completely disabled the 5 GHz band by disabling the wireless router radio.

Comment: Well the `Belkin N600 DB` adapter supports 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz.  If you router supports broadcasting at both 5.0 Ghz and 2.4Ghz you really should connected at 5.0 Ghz if you want the speed.  2.4 Ghz often has way to much interference which raises the question what does the interference look like?

Comment: @Ramhound: [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZaO8nU5.png) Here is a picture of the interference using inSIDDer. When I tried using 5 GHz, I would drop and have difficulty connecting.

Comment: @G-Man: Thank you for improving the post anyway, even after my failed suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your signal is being degraded by the walls/floor. At 2.4Ghz, the signal will have an easier time going through objects, so leave the 5GHz connection for anything that is in line-of-sight.

Other than making things too complex with extra repeaters and/or APs, you could take a look at powerline adapters. You can set things up like so:

First Floor
MODEM > ROUTER > WIFI | PowerLine Adapter | PC

Second Floor
PowerLine Adapter > Switch > WiFi | PC

You can make changes to this setup to only account for what you need. As is, this setup would let you have a decent WiFi signal on both floors and leave room for other wired devices.

Comment: Even when I put my phone next to the router, I get poor speeds. I tried using a Belkin N600 DB router but I got the same speeds. Are my settings for my router messed up?

Comment: That's strange. Try changing the available modes for wifi to only N or whatever the highest is. Check your speeds with just the phone connected.

Comment: I set it to n only and I'll report back in about an hour with speed tests.

Answer (score 0):

I Found this on another forum regarding the Belkin N600. I tried it and it made a huge difference.Try disabling the Intellistream feature.

Media Features > Intellistream > disable > apply.

Intellistream tries to hold bandwidth for each device but in a typical family household this means that a portion of the bandwidth is sitting idle. I just disabled mine and the bandwidth went from 20Mb upto the 50mb that I pay for.